# What is the difference between Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

I am relatively new to Linux operating systems and I'm trying to find out more about them. Unfortunately, I cant find a whole lot of good sources about them. Right now I get a bit confused and mixed up with all the different Linux options out there

Can anyone tell me the difference between Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and Lubuntu?

Comment: There's other options than ubuntu - ubuntu is based off debian, and there's other families of distributions as well

Comment: @MalwareManiac: SE has an AskUbuntu forum, they may well have a wealth of info over there

Comment: @Simon thks will have to check that out

Comment: @MalwareManiac: Welcome, Merry Christmas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main difference is the default window manager. Xubuntu and Lubuntu are usually used with older and less powerful computers. In detail:

**Ubuntu** comes with [**Unity**](http://unity.ubuntu.com) a shell running over the GNOME Desktop environment. Unity is mean to be easy to use for most users.

**Kubuntu** uses [**KDE**](http://www.kde.org) as the default desktop environment. KDE has got a lot of configurations and graphic effects and is good for power users who want to costumize a lot their environment.

**Xubuntu** uses [**XFCE**](http://www.xfce.org) a very clean desktop environment. XFCE is easy to use and uses less system resources than KDE and Unity (Gnome).

**Lubuntu** uses [**LXDE**](http://lxde.org) as the the window manager. LXDE is designed to work well with computers on the low end of the performance spectrum such as older resource-constrained machines.

All the versions of Ubuntu share the same packets and packet manager (apt-get), and they releases follow the main Ubuntu release (every 6 months). The release name is composed as year.month, so for example 12.10 is the release of October 2012.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference is the *default* window manager they include:

- Ubuntu:  **Gnome**
- Xubuntu:  **XFCE**
- Kubuntu:  **KDE**
- Lubuntu:  **LDXE**

However, since they all use the same package manager and default Ubuntu package repository, it's entirely possible to "convert" a given Ubuntu installation to another one of the variants listed above (and vice-versa) by adding & removing the correct packages.

Comment: +1 for a good answer but the other one has a bit more info